# Wordpress and plugins

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

How can i add a javascript function to the php?

Im trying this and nothing happens

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: PluginTest
Description: Just a test.
Version: 1.0.0
*/

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','c_leo_init');

function c_leo_init() {
  $src = plugins_url('js/lb_carrosel.js', __FILE__);

  wp_register_script( 'lb_carrosel', $src );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'lb_carrosel' );

}
```

My js function

```
function lb_carrosel(){
  alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `lb_carrosel()` in your JS file? Did you check the browser developer tools to see if the JS file is being loaded?

Comment: I did check, no errors

Comment: Ok, but the JS code that you posted here will do *nothing*... You're not telling your function to run... it won't self execute...

Answer (score 1):

In your JS file, you may need to call the function `lb_carrosel()`:

```
function lb_carrosel(){
  alert('hi');
}

lb_carrosel();
```